# Send "carrierwave" gem attachments via email Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading, mercury-editor

I am using Carrierwave gem + Mercury Editor and I want allow users to create mail campaigns and send them. Everything works well, but I have problems with inline images.

In image_uploader.rb I have

```
def store_dir
  "#{uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

I have newsletters.contents column, and it includes preformatted HTML from Mercury including images.

So in email .eml file I have path like `<img src="uploads/...">` instead of `<img src="http://uploads/...">` If I change path to `#{Rails.root}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}` uploading not working at all.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding gsub in mercury_update controller action

```
def mercury_update
    newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id])
    newsletter.title = params[:content][:newsletter_title][:value]
    newsletter.content = params[:content][:newsletter_content][:value]
    newsletter.update_attributes(content: newsletter.content.sub!('<img src="/uploads/', '<img src="http://host.com/uploads/'))
    newsletter.save!
    render text: ""
end
```

But I feel it is ugly solution